# Alterar a validação de data do script do formato mm/dd/yyyy para o formato dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript

Tenho um script que valida data no formato mm/dd/yyyy mas gostaria de alterar essa validação no formato dd/mm/yyyy.

**SCRIPT**

```
    function validarData(fld) {
    var testMo, testDay, testYr, inpMo, inpDay, inpYr, msg
    var inp = fld.value
    var testDate = new Date(inp)
    testMo = testDate.getMonth() + 1
    testDay = testDate.getDate()
    testYr = testDate.getFullYear()
    inpMo = parseInt(inp.substring(0, inp.indexOf("/")), 10)
    inpDay = parseInt(inp.substring((inp.indexOf("/") + 1), inp.lastIndexOf("/")), 10)
    inpYr = parseInt(inp.substring((inp.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), inp.length), 10)
    if (isNaN(inpMo) || isNaN(inpDay) || isNaN(inpYr)) {
        msg = "There is some problem with your date entry."
    }
    if (isNaN(testMo) || isNaN(testDay) || isNaN(testYr)) {
        msg = "Couldn't convert your entry to a valid date. Try again."
    }
    if (testMo != inpMo || testDay != inpDay || testYr != inpYr) {
        msg = "Check the range of your date value."
    }
    if (msg) {
        alert(msg)
        setTimeout("doSelection(document.forms['" + 
        fld.form.name + "'].elements['" + fld.name + "'])", 0)
        return false
    } else {
        alert("Data OK");
        return true
    }
}

function doSelection(fld) {
    fld.focus()
    fld.select()
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="entryForm" onSubmit="return false">
Entre com a data (dd/mm/yyyy): <input type="text" name="startDate" onChange="validarData(this)">
</form>
```

Tentei fazer algumas inversões em testMo com testDay, inpMo com inpDay mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única coisa que fiz foi formatar o `fld.value`, deixei no formato que ele entende, mm/dd/yyyy, sendo assim, dei um `var testDate = new Date(inp)` com o `inp` formatado, logo ele válida a data do jeito certo, depois é só fazer a validação normalmente.

```js
function validarData(fld) {
  var testMo, testDay, testYr, inpMo, inpDay, inpYr, msg
  var inp = fld.value

  inp = parseInt(inp.substring((inp.indexOf("/") + 1), inp.lastIndexOf("/")), 10) + "/" + parseInt(inp.substring(0, inp.indexOf("/")), 10) + "/" + parseInt(inp.substring((inp.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), inp.length), 10)
  console.log(inp);
  var testDate = new Date(inp)
  testMo = testDate.getMonth() + 1
  testDay = testDate.getDate()
  testYr = testDate.getFullYear()
  inpMo = parseInt(inp.substring(0, inp.indexOf("/")), 10)
  inpDay = parseInt(inp.substring((inp.indexOf("/") + 1), inp.lastIndexOf("/")), 10)
  inpYr = parseInt(inp.substring((inp.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), inp.length), 10)

  if (isNaN(inpMo) || isNaN(inpDay) || isNaN(inpYr)) {
    msg = "There is some problem with your date entry."
  }
  if (isNaN(testMo) || isNaN(testDay) || isNaN(testYr)) {
    msg = "Couldn't convert your entry to a valid date. Try again."
  }
  if (testMo != inpMo || testDay != inpDay || testYr != inpYr) {
    msg = "Check the range of your date value."
  }
  if (msg) {
    alert(msg)
    setTimeout("doSelection(document.forms['" +
      fld.form.name + "'].elements['" + fld.name + "'])", 0)
    return false
  } else {
    alert("Data OK");
    return true
  }
}

function doSelection(fld) {
  fld.focus()
  fld.select()
}
```

```html
<form name="entryForm" onSubmit="return false">
  Entre com a data (dd/mm/yyyy): <input type="text" name="startDate" onChange="validarData(this)">
</form>
```